# laravel validate with user function

Tags: php, laravel, validation, unique

blade.php

```
......
<tr>
  <td>{{ Form::label('cameraMac', 'Mac: ') }}</td>
  <td>{{ Form::text('cameraMac')}}</td>
</tr>
......
```

controller.php

```
$data = Input::all();
function transform($cameraMac) {
  return strtoupper($cameraMac);
}

//validation here

$user = User::find($data['user_id']);

if($data["cameraMac"])
{
    $user->camera_id = transform($data["cameraMac"]);
    Cloud_camera::create(['id' => transform($data["cameraMac"]), 'user_id' => $user->id]);
}

$user->save();
```

I need to transform the cameraMac to primary key to store in db. How can I use function `transform()` in the validation rule `'nullable|unique:cloud_cameras,id|size:6'`. That's to say, how can I call this function in the validation process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to somehow transform the input data you can use the `merge` method:

```
Input::merge(['cameraMac' => transform(Input::get('cameraMac')]);
$this->validate(Input::getFacadeRoot(), [
    'cameraMac' => 'nullable|unique:cloud_cameras,id|size:6'
]);
```

As a personal preference I would instead type-hint `Illuminate\Http\Request $request` in the controller method and then

```
$request->merge(['cameraMac' => transform($request->cameraMac)]);
$this->validate($request, ['cameraMac' => 'nullable|unique:cloud_cameras,id|size:6'
]);
```

Comment: is there a way to call this function in the validator, not trans the data first.

Comment: @KrisRoofe yes, you could create a custom ["form request"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation) where you can put your validation and authorization logic, and also override the `validationData` method and do the `merge` there.

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider [defining a middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#defining-middleware).

The middleware will perform the transformation and merge the result back to the request before hitting the controller.

```
class TransformId {
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
        // shout out to @alepeino
        $request->merge(['cameraMac' => transform($request->cameraMac)]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you shure, that you want the field `cameraMac` be nullable as a (more or less) primary key?
You should also use the `int` validation for using the `size` validation.
The third parameter of `unique` [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#available-validation-rules) is the `except` which will ignore the given ID.
Your validation in the controller could look like this

```
$except_id = $request->input('cameraMac', null);

$this->validate($request, [
  'cameraMac' => 'nullable|unique:cloud_cameras,id,'.$except_id.'|int|size:6'
]);
```

[One example](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) how you can show errors of your validation in the views will be this

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Yeah It's a primary key. When it exits a new camera will be created. And bind to a user. if not exists the camera_id of the user is null.

Answer (score 1):

For now I trans the input data first, then validate it in the below way.

**But I'm looking a way to call this funciton in the validation.**

```
$data = Input::all();
$data['cameraMac'] = transform($data['cameraMac']);
$rules = array(
  'id' => 'required|unique:cloud_printers,id|size:6',
  'cameraMac' => 'unique:cloud_cameras,id|size:6',
);
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
if ($validator->fails())
  return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
```

Comment: The validation rule is to compare one object with another one or a rule. It's not there to transform the data before you compare it. Why do you want it to have there, so it looks nicer? and should it be saved to the database with upper case? if yes, you have to transform it before.

Comment: @mimo The upper transform is just a simple example, actually I do some encrypt on it.

Comment: So you just want to transform it for the validation and then it should be normal again? You could write a custom validation tag and do the whole validation in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules):

```
Validator::extend('transformUpper', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
   return strtoupper($value);
});
```

Then use the new rule in the Request as usual:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'cameraMac' => 'required|transformUpper'
]);
```

Comment: How can I use the custom validation and the unique validation together? I want the transformed cameraMac to be unique in the database.

Comment: Validator return true or false, I don't think your code will change the input value of cameraMac.